# Механизм INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql

Запрос вида

```
SELECT  *
FROM `stena2`
INNER JOIN `stena3`
ON `stena2`.`author`=`stena3`.`author`
```

возвращает строки таблицы `stena3`. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что ты не stena3 делаешь JOIN

[объяснение в картинках](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html)

Comment: Надеюсь детские рисунки мне помогут...шансов нету...